# 'Wrinkles' when modeling?

Tags: modeling

I'm new to blender and 3D Modeling, in fact, this is my first face/head for a project I'm working on. For some reason, I have these weird 'wrinkles' when I set the face to shade smooth (especially around the nose). I've tried cutting a few of the quads into tris so they'd have more space to bend, but that doesn't seem to be doing much. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/76mIH.jpg

Comment: You say you have set your model to use smooth shading but your image is still showing flat shading? (Hard edges). To Shade Smooth: Edit mode > Select all > Face menu > Shade Smooth. If you still see some hard edges then click on the Object Data Properties icon (the little green triangle icon in the vertical list on the right side) > Normals > and if the Auto Smooth is enabled then increase the angle until hard edges disappear.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIFs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: I was going to add the picture for you, then I realized it was an entire gallery...

Comment: I didn't notice all the other images :)  It looks like you have watched some video tutorials on head topology but not paid enough attention to the edge flow when creating the nose. At this stage you need to keep the mesh as simple as possible. Check out this video on head edge flow and compare how little geometry is used to create the nose and how few edge loops there are around the mouth.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=im9XZf2C1s0   I would suggest watching a couple more tutorials and then start again this time aim to keep it a simple as possible and edge loops more evenly spaced..